# Logstash date filter configuration

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to replace @timestamp with tstamp but it is not working. What am I missing here? Here is my configuration

```
 date {
        match => ["tstamp","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"]
        target => "@timestamp"
 }
```

and the sample date entry is like this

```
2016-04-02T09:29:50.348Z
2016-04-02T08:52:49Z
2016-04-02T02:52:50.000Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"ISO8601"` to match the date:

```
date {
    match => ["tstamp","ISO8601"]
    target => "@timestamp"
}
```